# Is the following graph of the function $f(x) = \ln (2\sin \frac{x}{2})$ right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

[image]

In my text book about Fourier Analysis, $x$ ranges from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.I think when $x$ is from $-\pi$ to $0$, $\displaystyle \ln(2\sin\frac{x}{2})$ is meaningless. Why does the left part of the figure exist?

Comment: They might have meant $\ln|2\sin(x/2)|$ instead.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $\ln \left(2 \vert \sin(x/2) \vert\right)$?

Comment: yes,it's ln(2sin(x/2))! it has no absolute value sign.

Comment: Well then, they made an error.

Comment: In the image itself, it is obviously wrong. However, the text referring to the image (if it exists) may be using $\ln|2\sin(x/2)|$.

Comment: The picture seems to have more problems than the one pointed out. For example, $\ln\left(2\sin\left({\pi \over2}\right)\right) \approx .6931$, whereas the graph seems to claim it is near $\pi$ instead. What book is this? I don't know in what context this plot and function were given, but I would suggest carefully checking other material presented in the book.

Comment: Maybe the book is wrong.

Comment: I just plotted the graph on Wolfram, and it turns out they must mean $\text{Re}(f(x)).$ So the book may not be wrong after all. And in retrospect, this assumption would be useful in discussing Fourier series indeed.

Comment: [Check it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%282*sin%28x%2F2%29%29).

Comment: I know nothing about complex anylisis,so I don't understand your meaning.Could you explain in detail?

Comment: @parkning Sure. Given a complex number $z = \text{a} + \text{b}i \ (\text{a}, \text{b} \in \mathbb{R})$, $ \text{Re}(\text{a} + \text{b}i) = \text{a}$. So, $\text{Re}(z)$ simply denotes the real part of $z$. So when I did $\text{Re}(f(x))$, it simply meant determine the real part of $f$ for all $x$.